# Uploaded application is not working on certain devices while installing from play store but application is working if directly install release apk

Tags: android

I am facing a very critical issue because it is draining my users. I have updated application on play store now what is happening is that application is not working on some devices. And after installation from play store, it shows splash screen & after that application either closes automatically or it is showing runtime exception error & closes. This is happening for some users only.

Here the main thing is that if I send the release application to that user directly, it is working perfectly. I have attached a video as well  for this particular issue. [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_OLUUxWSSqlElpjMY0chXQrMtoWwIPC/view?usp=drive_link)

I have used any third party libraries in the application.

Please help me with this issue as it is affecting user base & need to be fixed as soon as possible.

I have tried to create that issue by installing application on some devices but it is not happening on those devices. The big cache is that if I send the release version of that application to the users who are facing the issue, the release version apk working fine without any error.

I am expecting for solution as soon as possible. this is really a big headache & I am constantly finding solution since past 3 days and I haven't find anything that can clear this. This is really depressing. please help.